# F6 for compiling?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have become accustomed to using <kbd>F6</kbd> to compile the current document.  A third-party install appears to have turned this function off.  (<kbd>F6</kbd> no longer does anything.)

Can anyone tell me how to get it back?

I'm using VS2008

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Tools > Options > Keybord
```

This dialog lets you bind keyboard shortcuts to your heart's content.  BTW this is how you bind keyboard shortcuts to custom IDE macros as well.

Answer (score 2):

VMware's integrated debugging tool did this to me too. You can change this back to whatever you want, but every time you restart Visual Studio your keyboard shortcuts will be changed again.

The only way I could fix this was to remove the VMware debugging tools.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks.  The dialog: Tools > Options > Keybord
Allowed me to set the keyboard back to *Visual C# 2005*.  So far, this seems to be what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Its become a habit for me to use Ctrl + Shift + B to build my solutions.  I know this doesnt answer your question, but I thought I would point it out.

Another keyboard shortcut is use constantly is Alt + Shift + F10.  It opens the drop menu from the little red square under a change (the autocorrect type thing, I'm not sure what its called, also works for autocorrect in all the MS apps)